# Trying to Create Case and Person on Create Page MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have created a "Create" page with the following code. I know it is not best practice, but I am unsure of how to do it otherwise. Here's the code:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,Victim")] Case @case, Person person)
{
    var caseVictims = @case.Victim;
    db.Cases.Add(@case);
    db.SaveChanges();      
    var caseId = @case.ID; //need this
    if (caseVictims != null && caseVictims != "")
    {
        if (caseVictims.Contains(";"))
        { // { "First1,Last1;First2,Last2" }
                string[] victims = caseVictims.Split(';');
                foreach (var victim in victims)
                {
                        person.CaseId = caseId;
                        person.Victim = true;
                        person.FullName = victim;
                        person.Case = null;
                        db.People.Add(person);
                        db.SaveChanges();
                }
        }
        else
        {
                person.CaseId = caseId;
                person.Victim = true;
                person.FullName = caseVictims;
                person.Case = null;
                db.People.Add(person);
                db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(@case);
}
```

I would like to be able to create a Case and use information from that Case such as `@case.Victim` to populate the "People" table. Right now it works correctly, except that it creates two "Cases" every time I click submit. This is the case no matter how many "Victims" I have. If I comment out the "Victim" part it creates only one Case as expected. Thank you for any help!

EDIT:
Here are the models

```
public partial class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int CaseId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Victim { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public virtual Case Case { get; set; }
}
```

.

```
public partial class Case
{    
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Victim { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> People { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You are definitely not using the MVC pattern correctly here.  All of this needs to move to the controller or other logic processing layer.

Comment: Can you show your People and Cases models?

Comment: This is in controller

Comment: @Roman where do you think the `Create` code is?

Comment: Try moving the `db.SaveChanges()` to just before the `RedirectToAction` and `View` - it looks like multiple victims will create duplicate records, but I'm not 100% sure how `db.SaveChanges()` works.

Comment: @freedomn-m when i move `db.SaveChanges();` to just before `RedirectToAction` it only creates the last `person` to be added. I did get it to make one `Case` finally by adding `person.Case = null;` just before `db.People.Add(person);` but now every other `person` doesn't have a `CaseId`

Comment: @freedomn-m also, I forgot to mention, duplicate records are still created when I moved the `db.SaveChanges();`

Comment: Which version and model of EntityFramework are you using?  Generally the practice would be to add the `Case` to the context, as you are doing, then just set `person.Case = @case` and save it all at the end, letting the context detect the hierarchy from the foreign keys between `Case` and `Person`.  Shouldn't explicitly need the case ID at all in this instance.

Comment: Hey @MikeGuthrie I actually just posted my answer right before I saw your comment that did basically the same thing that you suggested. I'm glad to know I was on the right track.

Comment: @daxter your original snippet was not clear to me.  I see that you've made updates and figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it to work exactly how I wanted. Here's the final code:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,Victim")] Case @case, Case lastCase, Person person)
{
    var caseVictims = @case.Victim;
    lastCase = @case;
    db.Cases.Add(@case);
    db.SaveChanges();      
    var caseId = @case.ID; //need this
    if (caseVictims != null && caseVictims != "")
    {
        if (caseVictims.Contains(";"))
        { // { "First1,Last1;First2,Last2" }
                string[] victims = caseVictims.Split(';');
                foreach (var victim in victims)
                {
                        person.CaseId = caseId;
                        person.Victim = true;
                        person.FullName = victim;
                        person.Case = lastCase;
                        db.People.Add(person);
                        db.SaveChanges();
                }
        }
        else
        {
                person.CaseId = caseId;
                person.Victim = true;
                person.FullName = caseVictims;
                person.Case = lastCase;
                db.People.Add(person);
                db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(@case);
}
```

Thanks for all of the help everyone! :)